# how webserver communnicates with Database server

Tags: php, database

We know that when we send request from our browser to the webserver(Apache).Its an Http request.Suppose the database is on different webserver,How the webserver will communicate with the database server?Php is present at my Webserver but not at Database server.Any help will be Appreciated.I am not sure it could be SOAP or XML,Thats why I am asking

Comment: I hd just read that http://www.masterhosts.net/web-server/how_do_web_servers_communicate_with_databases.shtml

Comment: When you do `mysql_connect("server2.localnet", user, pw);` it opens a socket connection to your mysqld server, which can therefore be distinct from your webserver.

Answer (score 2):

It is not HTTP, SOAP or XML
It is most likely database's own TCP/IP-based protocol implemented in database API functions compiled in PHP module loaded by PHP.

database server is a regular daemon, "listening" for inbound TCP/IP connections. Thus, there is no difference where it placed - on the same server or remote one.

So, PHP opens connection to mysql server much like as HTTP client opens a connection to HTTP server or email client opens connection to POP3 or SMTP server.

Comment: PostgreSQL does not use MySQL's protocol, and it is not PHP's module that implements it in any case.

Comment: Oh really? You opened my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Over the network, with a specialized protocol implemented by the database libraries.

Comment: FreeTDS or ODBC aren't propiertary ones, I believe. If you like a nit-picking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The application on the web server creates a socket connection to the database server, and sends messages back and forth using a protocol created specifically for database communications, which is unique to each different database software.

Comment: Database servers from multiple vendors use TDS, therefore not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link for questions like What is PHP's MySQL Extension? What is an API? What is a Connector? What is a Driver? PHP Data Objects (PDO) and many more...
[php-mysqli.overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-php-mysqli.overview.html)